# How to redesign an AlertDialog

Tags: android, eclipse, android-widget

I would like to redesign my alert dialog(to change the windows of this one). I tried to search in the net, I didn't find something useful. I also tried to put a layout for the alert dialog, but i didn't find the system to do this... I'm a beginner in Android.  My code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class Magie extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.magie);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        final Button magie1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bma1);
        magie1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            magie1();
            }

        });

        final Button magie2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bma2);
        magie2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            magie2();
            }

        });

        final Button magie3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bma3);
        magie3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            magie3();
            }

        });

        final Button magie4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bma4);
        magie4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){


            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            magie4();
            }

        });
    }

    private void magie1(){
        AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        ad.setTitle("title1");
        ad.setMessage("text1");
        ad.show();
    }

    private void magie2(){
        AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        ad.setTitle("title2");
        ad.setMessage("text2");
        ad.show();
    }

    private void magie3(){
        AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        ad.setTitle("title3");
        ad.setMessage("text3");
        ad.show();
    }

    private void magie4(){
        AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        ad.setTitle("title4");
        ad.setMessage("Text4");
        ad.show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The window decorations and theming for alerts vary radically from Android version to Android version, and are also frequently customized by OEM modifications of a given version. There is no safe way to recycle android AlertDialog system resources and theming in an activity. Some required resources are hidden; and substantial parts of AlertDialogs are built with code rather than layout files. Strange but true.

This leaves you with one of two choices.

(1) Use AlertDialog.Builder.setView() to insert custom layout into an alert dialog.

Definitely the preferred approach. There are minor theming issues in this approach. It's wise not to assume that the background is white, or black, and wise not to override default colors on any of your controls. (e.g. Samsung Galaxy Tab 1.0 which shows all alerts on a blue background even when using a light theme, and shows unreadable black text on a blue background when using Light themes). If you have to use explicit colors in your view (or use a Light themes), make sure your view has a solid background (white for light themes, black for default themes).

Use AlertDialog.Builder methods for adding dialog buttons, if you can. And don't forget to call AlertDialog.Builder.setIcon, and AlertDialog.Builder.setTitle if you want a title-bar on your Alert dialog.

(2) Build an activity that mimics alert for the Android version of your choice.

It's not really possible to use Android system resources at runtime when doing this. However, you can steal resources from the Android SDK, if required. Stock resource files for all versions of android can found in the "platforms" directory of the SDK. The general idea is that you would set your styles for your activity that remove all decoration, and then emulate window decorations in your layout file.

```
styles.xml:

<style name="Theme.TutorialDialog" parent="android:style/Theme.Black">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
</style>

AndroidManifest.xml:
     <activity
          android:name="com.twoplay.twoplayer2.TutorialActivity"
          ...
      android:theme="@style/TutorialDialog" 
     />
```

This produces a transparent Activity that floats on top of the Activity immediately below it. It's then up to you to recreate title bars, and buttons. Use padding or margins in your layout to put a transparent border around your content. Scavenge what resources you can from the sdk platforms directory. No, there's no off-the-shelf way to recreate the button styles that alert dialogs use, either. This is a difficult way to go, and should be used only as a last resort.

A  pattern that's sometimes useful: create an Activity that wraps an alert dialog. Use the custom theme given above to remove window decorations. In Activity.onCreate, you do not set a view; just leave it empty. Then within onCreate, create and show an alert. Button handlers for the alert then call Activity.finish() on the enclosing activity. This can be useful if you want to recycle an alert dialog cleanly across multiple activities; or if you need to launch an alert dialog in response to system activity from the background, or notification bar button presses, &c.

Hope that helps. The short answer: use AlertDialog.Builder.setView if at all humanly possible.